# Why Spring is not recognizing my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with BasicAuth?

Tags: spring-security

I have this maven module project where I want to use BasicAuth. All my business and controllers are imported as dependencies. At my 'main' project, I have this `App.java` class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "controller", "service" })
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And at the same directory I have

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

static final String adminRole = "ADMIN";
static final String standardRole = "STANDARD";

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
      .withUser("user").password("{noop}pass").roles(standardRole)
      .and()
      .withUser("admin").password("{noop}admin").roles(adminRole, standardRole);
}

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  static final String adminRole = "ADMIN";
  static final String standardRole = "STANDARD";

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
      .withUser("user").password("{noop}pass").roles(standardRole)
      .and()
      .withUser("admin").password("{noop}admin").roles(adminRole, standardRole);
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/seriousInfo").hasRole(adminRole)
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
          .and().httpBasic();
  }

}
```

Is it necessary any other info at `application.yml`? Even with this when I execute it I get logs with some random generated password

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation. then you can remove the `@Configuration` because it is being called in by the `@EnableWebSecurity`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableWebSecurity.html